# How can prevent multi UIAlertView at same time?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uialertview

my app use UIAlertView if network fail.
and i use multi network request async.

when network is fail at same time,
UIAlerView is show over and over.

i try set bool variable controller. but UIAlertView show method call same time. yes it's same microsecond...

```
if (!self.isAlertAlreadyShow) {
    self.isAlertAlreadyShow = YES;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"fail_data_title", nil)
                          message:NSLocalizedString(@"fail_data_message", nil) 
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"close", @"close") 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

how can show UIAlerView only one?

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with the intricacies of threading. You could use `NSNotificationCenter` to send a message to the UI thread that displays the message and keeps track of whether it's showing or not.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomeMessageName" object:self];
```

And of course subscribe to this message in your main thread (possibly AppDelegate) before you use the code above:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showAlertView) name:nil object:nil];
```